# Нахождение нужного <template> по заголовку из JSONa

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, json

На странице очень много элементов . Я получаю json и нужно найти темплейт в котором есть заголовок, который равен заголовку из jsonа и затем извлечь все содержимое этого темплейта. Но, честно говоря, у меня пока ни одной идеи как это сделать. 
Можно это сделать и если да то как?

все темплейты подобные этому

```
<template class="templ1">
    <div>
        <label>Label 1</label>
    </div>
</template>
```

json содержит стрингу "Label 1|Label 2|Label 3"
которую я сплитую по "|" и записываю в массив, и поиск происходит по каждому элементу (к примеру "Label 1")

Comment: приведите пожалуйста код с примером того что вы получаете и где вы хотите его искать?

Comment: Добавила пример :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Самый незамороченный вариант

```js
const findTemplate = str => {
  // можно вынести из функции
  const templates = [...document.querySelectorAll('template')];
  return templates.find(t => t.innerHTML.includes(str));
}

console.log(findTemplate('Label 2'));
```

```html
<template class="templ1">
    <div>
        <label>Label 1</label>
    </div>
</template>
<template class="templ2">
    <div>
        <label>Label 2</label>
    </div>
</template>
<template class="templ3">
    <div>
        <label>Label 3</label>
    </div>
</template>
<template class="templ4">
    <div>
        <label>Label 4</label>
    </div>
</template>
```